# Sharing methods and properties between "classes"

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a "base class" in javascript that I call "main" in my example below. I want to use some methods and variables from the main class on all child classes that I create.

I have made two examples below with my current ideas. I suppose the the latter is preferred since I will create some instances of `main`, and I heard that `prototype` is useful when having more than one instance.

Should I go with any of these 2 methods, or try to create inheritance between the "classes"? If inheritance is preferred, please provide an example, since I don't know how ti implement that.

```
var main = (function(){

    var out = function() {};

    out.staticMethod = function(){
        alert('hello world');
    };

    return out;

})();

var child = (function(main){

    var out = function() {};

    out.prototype.useMainFunction = function(){
        main.staticMethod();
    };

    return out;

})(main);

var c = new child();
c.useMainFunction();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQPFJ/

```
var main = (function(){

    var out = function() {};

    out.prototype.publicMethod = function(){
        alert('hello world');
    };

    return out;

})();

var child = (function(main){

    var out = function() {};

    out.prototype.useMainFunction = function(){
        main.publicMethod();
    };

    return out;

})(new main());

var c = new child();
c.useMainFunction();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQPFJ/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a different approach:

```
function Main(){
  this.message = "Parent";
}

Main.prototype.out = function(){
    alert(this.message);
};

function Child(){
   this.message = "Child";
};

Child.prototype = new Main();

var child = new Child();
child.out();

var main = new Main();
main.out();
```

This approach creates two classes using the `function constructor`.  The first class `main` is given a property `out`, which is assigned a function.  The second class `Child` has its prototype assigned to a new instance of `Main`, creating inheritance between the two classes.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8QW46/

**In regards your question about which approach is best**

I would suggest using the first method which does not use prototype.  The reason I would suggest this is that your not actually using classes (in Javascript Classes are better described as object definitions).  Your creating instances of a function.  Usually prototype is used to add functions to all instances of a class.

Here is an example of what you will not be able to achieve using your approach, which would be available with classes/object definitions: http://jsfiddle.net/smmb3/

Comment: Thanks for the input. What about implementing inheritance in my example? I think that I want to stick to the closures.

Comment: @Johan Could you explain why you are using the closures?

Comment: I just like to only expose certain methods and properties to "the outside" :)

Comment: @Johan if encapsulation is important to you, I think this approach works.  I'm not sure its possible to have true inheritance between two closures, since it really defeats the purpose of them being self enclosed.

Comment: @Johan Then again if encapsulation is really your goal there is always this: http://jsfiddle.net/axELM/

Comment: Okay thanks. Which of my examples makes most sense? Since my methods will be re-used on several childs I suppose that the latter of my examples makes most sense, since it will be a bit faster?

Comment: "your not actually using classes. Your creating instances of a function". Isn't that always the case in javascript where classes don't exist?

Comment: @Johan Agreed, however `class` seems to be the term used when functions are used to simulate a class.  The difference is your creating multiple `function` objects which will not share changes to the prototype, whereas using the the `constructor function` approach will share the changes to the prototype between instances.  Good question BTW! Researching some of my responses was a good refresher.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Main(){
    this.out = function(message){
        alert(message);
    }
}

function Child(){
    this.message = "no more hello world programs";
}

Child.prototype = new Main;

var kid = new Child;
kid.out(kid.message);
```

Similar to @Kevin's answer however it is even less verbose, and much [DRYER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) then your current code.

Comment: And the repeat part in my code would be that i use a variable named "out" in both of my functions? If properties and methods should be accessible outside of the function, they need to be returned somehow.

Comment: @Johan yes the repeat is that you have an `out` method in both classes. It's just not needed in the subclass when your superclass already defines it. Unless your going to override the superclass method. And I'm not sure what you mean by accessible? The `out` method of the `Main` class is accessible: see http://jsfiddle.net/8NnsF/

Comment: Yes, but something which is not attached to `out` is not. From a performance point of view, do you know which of my examples that will perform best?

Comment: @Johan see Kevin's answer, what both of us have suggested is true inheritance; which doesn't seem to be what your looking for... Also I don't see what you mean by not attached to `out`.